# Unable to fetch parameters in test method using dataprovider

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Excel Reader:

package com.Excel.Read;

public class ReadFile
{
    static Sheet excelWSheet;

```
static Workbook excelWBook;

static Row row;

public static String[][] getExcelData(String fileName, String sheetName, int startRow,int targetRow, int startCol, int targetCol) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        String[][] arrayExcelData = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            excelWBook = WorkbookFactory.create(fs);
            int rowCount = excelWBook.getSheet(sheetName).getLastRowNum();
            int colCount;
            System.out.println(rowCount);
            arrayExcelData = new String[targetRow-startRow+1][targetCol-startCol+1];

            for(int i = startRow ; i < targetRow; i++) {
                colCount = excelWSheet.getRow(i).getLastCellNum();
                System.out.println(colCount);
                for (int j = startCol; j <= targetCol; j++) {
                    arrayExcelData[i-startRow][j-startCol] = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return arrayExcelData;
    }

}
```

TestClass:

package com.Excel.Read;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestDataProvider {

```
@Test(dataProvider="getlogincred")
public void setcred(String sUserName, String sPassword, String sexpectedMsg)
{
    System.out.println("UserName : " + sUserName);
    System.out.println("Password : " + sPassword);
    System.out.println("Msg : " + sexpectedMsg);
    System.out.println();
}

@DataProvider(name="getlogincred")
public String[][] getlogincred() throws Exception
{
    String[][] testObjArray = ReadFile.getExcelData("C:\\Users\\u6035997\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx", "Sheet1",2,5,2,4);

    return (testObjArray);
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

Data provide returns array of objects. So you have to return Array of Object by loading testObjArray  into that. Below is the simple example helps you

```
@Test(dataProvider="my data")
public void GoogelSeacrhTest(Hashtable<String, String> h) throws InterruptedException{

     //my code here

}

@DataProvider(name="my data")
public Object[][] testdata(){

    Hashtable<String, String> h=new Hashtable<>();
    h.put("search", "murali selenium");

    Object[][] ob={{h}};

    return ob;

}
```

So, you need to change

```
  public static String[][] getExcelData(String fileName, String sheetName, int startRow,int targetRow, int startCol, int targetCol) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException { }
```

to return object Object[][] instead of String[][], then, simply return than object passing required arguments in your data provider

```
 @DataProvider(name="getlogincred")
 public Object[][] getlogincred() throws Exception
 {
    return ReadFile.getExcelData("C:\\Users\\u6035997\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx", "Sheet1",2,5,2,4);
}
```

please refer doc [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) for more information.

Thank You,
Murali